# WPF Custom Control with children of the same type

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, children

I am trying to implement my own control, which can host one or more children of the same type as the control itself:

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="control1">
    <local:MyControl x:Name="control2">
        <local:MyControl x:Name="control3">
            <local:MyControl x:Name="control4">
                <local:MyControl x:Name="control5">
                    <local:MyControl x:Name="control6">
                        <local:MyControl x:Name="control7"/>
                    </local:MyControl>
                </local:MyControl>
            </local:MyControl>
       </local:MyControl>
   </local:MyControl>
</local:MyControl>
```

The problem that I have is that only the first instance is known as `root` and the others are children of the first one. And they may even be children of each other.

Here the code for MyControl class:

```
[ContentProperty("MyChildren")]
class MyControl : ItemsControl
{ 
    public List<MyControl> MyChildren
    {
        get { return (List<MyControl>)GetValue(MyChildrenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyChildrenProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Children.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyChildrenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyChildren", typeof(List<MyControl>), typeof(MyControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new List<MyControl>()));
}
```

This code is what I have tried, but this isn't working.

How do I implement a custom control that can host child controls of the same type, in which it should be possible to do things like in the example above?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. What is your question?

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I updatet my question and I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking something without doing any kind of research before. I know what I am talking about because if you had asked google about this, you would have known that controls in wpf need to be in visualtree and/or logicaltree and futhermore you would have read somewhere that controls shall not be stored in a simple list but instead in a UIElementCollection which manages adding and removing controls to or from visualtree automatically for you.

Just google your issue please and you will know what I am talking about. There are tons of tutorials about how to write a custom controls. There are awesome tuts on msdn about custom controls in wpf.